# Stepper with pure javascript - highlight specifc step

Tags: javascript

I would like to make it skip step 1 and step 2 and directly jump and highlight on step 3. I tried to do it my own but I only managed to highlight step 3 but not step 1 and 2. I want it to be randomly jump to any step as long as I change it on my javascript.

Is it possible to do so? Below is my snippet. You may try to run it to see the result.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

```js
const bullets = [...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];

let current = -1;

function next() {
 if(!bullets[current+1]){
  return false;
 }
 current = Math.min(current + 1, bullets.length - 1);
 bullets[current].classList.remove('unhovered');
 bullets[current].classList.add('hovered');
 if(bullets[current].classList.contains('uncompleted')){
  bullets[current].classList.remove('uncompleted');
  bullets[current].classList.add('completed');
 }
}

function previous() {
 if (bullets[current]) {
  bullets[current].classList.remove('hovered');
  bullets[current].classList.add('unhovered');
  if(bullets[current].classList.contains('completed')){
   bullets[current].classList.remove('completed');
   bullets[current].classList.add('uncompleted');
  }
 }
 current = Math.max(current - 1, -1);
}

function randomto2() {
 current = Math.min(current + 3, bullets.length - 1);
 bullets[current].classList.remove('unhovered');
 bullets[current].classList.add('hovered');
 bullets[current].classList.remove('uncompleted');
 bullets[current].classList.add('completed');
}
```

```css
.progressbar{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
 align-items:flex-end;
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}
.item{
 text-align:center;
 width:20%;
 position:relative;
}
.text{
 height:50px;
 margin:10px 0px;
 color:#000;
}
.bullet{
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
 transition:background-color 500ms;
 line-height:20px;
}
.bullet.hovered{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#0c8a43;
 bottom:10px;
 border:1px solid #0c8a43;
}
.bullet.unhovered{
 color:#000;
 background-color:#fff;
 bottom:10px;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.bullet.uncompleted:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 bottom:80px;
 height:1px;
 width:calc(133% - 21px);
 background-color:#53565A;
 margin-left:7px;  
}
.bullet.completed:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 bottom:80px;
 height:1px;
 width:calc(133% - 21px);
 background-color:#0c8a43;
 margin-left:7px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet unhovered uncompleted">1</div>
  <div class="text">Hello Hello Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet unhovered uncompleted">2</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet unhovered uncompleted">3</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet unhovered">4</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div onclick="previous();">Previous</div>
<div onclick="next();">Next</div>
<div onclick="randomto2();">Random to 2</div>
```

Comment: Can't you do a loop from 0 to current (e.g. 3), like `for (let i = 0; i < 3) { bullets[i].classList.add('hovered'); // and all your other hightlight code }`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
const bullets = [...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];

let current = -1;

function next(upto=0) {
 if(!bullets[current+1]){
  return false;
 }
 current = Math.min(current + 1, bullets.length - 1);
 bullets[current].classList.remove('unhovered');
 bullets[current].classList.add('hovered');
 if(bullets[current].classList.contains('uncompleted')){
  bullets[current].classList.remove('uncompleted');
  bullets[current].classList.add('completed');
 }
  if (upto > 0) {
    next(upto-1);
  }
}

function previous() {
 if (bullets[current]) {
  bullets[current].classList.remove('hovered');
  bullets[current].classList.add('unhovered');
  if(bullets[current].classList.contains('completed')){
   bullets[current].classList.remove('completed');
   bullets[current].classList.add('uncompleted');
  }
 }
 current = Math.max(current - 1, -1);
}

function randomto2() {
 someValue = Math.min(current + 3, bullets.length - 1);
  next(someValue);
}
```

```css
.progressbar{
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
 align-items:flex-end;
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-bottom:40px;
}
.item{
 text-align:center;
 width:20%;
 position:relative;
}
.text{
 height:50px;
 margin:10px 0px;
 color:#000;
}
.bullet{
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 display:inline-block;
 transition:background-color 500ms;
 line-height:20px;
}
.bullet.hovered{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#0c8a43;
 bottom:10px;
 border:1px solid #0c8a43;
}
.bullet.unhovered{
 color:#000;
 background-color:#fff;
 bottom:10px;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
.bullet.uncompleted:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 bottom:80px;
 height:1px;
 width:calc(133% - 21px);
 background-color:#53565A;
 margin-left:7px;  
}
.bullet.completed:after{
 content:'';
 position:absolute;
 bottom:80px;
 height:1px;
 width:calc(133% - 21px);
 background-color:#0c8a43;
 margin-left:7px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="progressbar">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet unhovered uncompleted">1</div>
  <div class="text">Hello Hello Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet unhovered uncompleted">2</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet unhovered uncompleted">3</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="bullet unhovered">4</div>
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div onclick="previous();">Previous</div>
<div onclick="next();">Next</div>
<div onclick="randomto2();">Random to 2</div>
```

Comment: thanks! it works! is there any other ways instead of using next(upto=0)?

Comment: You could try a for loop like I mentioned in my comment. But @iustinian's recursive solution is even better IMHO, so I would stick to that.

Comment: It is very likely that there are other ways that I did not think of. You can wait for more answers.The main idea is that you have to call your next function as many times as needed in order to highlight all the bullets prior to your random bullet. If you are going to do the same for previous, you will have to keep in mind to check the direction you need to go: forward call next, backwards call previous.